# Send emoji from Android to iOS

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

I need to send the unicode of any kind of emoji country flag (for example \u1f1e7\u1f1ea) from Android to iOS.

This is my code:

```
String regexPattern = "[\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83c\\udfff]|[\\ud83d\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udfff]|[\\u2600-\\u27ff]"; 

    byte[] utf8 = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

    String string1 = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string1);
    List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(matcher.group());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matchList.size(); i++) {
        int unicode = Character.codePointAt(matchList.get(i), 0);
        text = text.replace(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(encodeCodepoint(unicode)), matchList.get(i));
        System.out.println(i + ":" + matchList.get(i));

    }
```

First problem: the matcher doesn't detect the unicode.

Second problem: if I send directly the unicode `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text)` to iOS device, is received this: u1f1e7u1f1ea.

Basically I'm trying to send country flag emojis to iOS devices but I can't. Others emojis like faces are sent successfully.

Comment: Have you tried to split them? I think it's an option to see if the flag is readable because I can see that you're trying to display 2 at the same time.

Comment: Federico, a flag unicode it's composed of two unicode codes. Extracted from https://esham.io/2014/06/unicode-flags: "the standard defines twenty-six “regional indicator symbols”, from U+1F1E6 REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER A to U+1F1FF REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER Z". I can't split it.